# How to convert div to image/canvas

Tags: image, html

I've tried convert a div to image with html2canvas but I get low quality. Is there a way to improve quality or another way to do this? I need this for print.

I found this site: http://fancyproductdesigner.com/jquery-plugin/business-card-designer/ but i don't know what tool they're using.

I've tried also convert my div to canvas with html2canvas but it's still low quality.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316065/set-quality-of-png-with-html2canvas

Comment: ..So you should make the element bigger before rendering it.