# Increase image DPI using Html2Canvas library

Tags: javascript, c#, html5-canvas

We are using Html2Canvas library to capture div element to an image. But captured image quality is not good. Please let us know how can we improve quality (DPI upto 300)

We have added below javascript code

```
$(‘#divId’).html2canvas({
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var imageData = { "imageData": canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0) };
                $('#ImageData').val(imageData);
                var sourceUrl = configuration.baseURL + "/ScreenShot";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: sourceUrl,
                    data: imageData,
                    success: function () {

                    },
                    error: function (a, errorStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(a, errorStatus, errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

C# code ::

```
public void ScreenShot(string imageData)
        {
            string trimmedData = imageData.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", string.Empty);
            byte[] uploadedImage = Convert.FromBase64String(trimmedData);
            byte[] tiffBytes;

            using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(uploadedImage))
            using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Bitmap.FromStream(inStream).Save(outStream, ImageFormat.Tiff);
                tiffBytes = outStream.ToArray();
            }

            string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + ".tiff";
            string path = Server.MapPath(fileName);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, tiffBytes);
        }
```

Comment: Please provide code samples of what you've already tried.

Comment: @Elad Stern: We have added sample code

Comment: Have you tried displaying Html2Canvas result in a browser? It might be the c# that makes it bad, not the JS. I use something very similar for generating PDFs with PHP (but jpg).

Answer (score -1):

Usually the screen resolution is near 100dpi, usualy a bit lower, so you cannot capture a higher resolution, because it's not available. The capture is a pixel by pixel capture of what's in the screen.

I don't know if yu can do so, but the only way to get a higher resolution is to cheat by zooming in in your browser, and capture the zoomed in div content. If you need 300 dpi you have to zoom at least x3.

The only other solution is to get the original capture, and use some library that can increase the resolution using interpolation, but you're not going to get a good quality.

Comment: can you please provide sample

Comment: sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316065/set-quality-of-png-with-html2canvas