# Change image size without losing quality via html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I take screenshot of the div via html2canvas. I want to change the size of caption div but without losing quality.

Here is my code example:

```
$(".meme-submit").on('click',(function() { 
    html2canvas($(".meme-img-upload"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {

            var extra_canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            extra_canvas.setAttribute('width',canvas.width*3);
            extra_canvas.setAttribute('height',canvas.height*3);

            var ctx = extra_canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height,0,0,canvas.width*3,canvas.height*3);

            $("#img_val").val(extra_canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));

            document.getElementById("upload-meme").submit();
        }
    });
}));
```

Is someone have idea?

Comment: Related question: [Set Quality of Png with html2canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316065/set-quality-of-png-with-html2canvas)

Comment: Yes, i know this post. I already read it and try to implement and use his code but it's not work. 
toDataURL() is empty.